# Am I understanding this loss function correctly?

Tags: deep-learning

I'm in the process of trying to reimplement the MatchLSTM model as described in the paper [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.07905.pdf). I understand most of the paper except for their definition of the loss function.

[image]

Am I correct to assume here that:
$$p(\mathbf{a} | \mathbf{H^r}) = \prod_k\mathbf{\beta}_k$$
where:
$$\beta_k = \begin{bmatrix}\beta_{k,1} & \dots & \beta_{k,J}\end{bmatrix} $$

If that is true, then what would the loss function be (note here that $\mathbf{H^r}$ is a function of $\mathbf{P}$ and $\mathbf{Q}$)? I'm pretty sure that the loss function is a scalar, but using my definition $\log p(\mathbf{a}_n |\mathbf{P}_n, \mathbf{Q}_n)$ would be a vector, and therefore the loss function would also be a vector. Any ideas? Please don't hesitate to ask me to provide more details!

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry I understand it now, I believe that the `kth` term in the sequence of products above is simply:

$$\beta_{k,t}$$

where `t` is the target class this makes sense as it is the result of the one-hot encoding!